# iPhone restarts when in sleep mode

Tags: ios, crash, iphone

### Update #2

I contacted apple support about the problem. After an extensive conversation with the tech person, we decide that this problem would need to be taken to an apple genius bar to be repaired.

### Update #1

After about 3 weeks of using the workaround listed below, the phone apparently crashed one time too many. After the crash, I hit the power button and the apple logo appeared for ~3 seconds, then disappeared. ~3 seconds later, the logo re-appeared. This loop seems to continue indefinitely. A hardware reset (both home and sleep button) only interrupts the cycle, not stop it. I have done another dfu mode restore, but no change occurred.

#### End update

I have an odd problem with my iPhone 5c. Whenever the phone's display is off and is not playing any audio it will within 2 minutes crash and shut down. If it is connected to power as well, it will automatically turn back on. Often when it has crashed, it will turn back on (show the apple logo on a black screen for ~30secs) when you simply hit the home button -- without touching the Sleep/Wake button since the crash.

I have replaced the battery with one from another 5c I had and the problem still persists, even though the issue was never present in the other 5c. This problem has been consistent over many iOS versions (7, 8, 9, 10). I have hard reset the phone, reset it to factory settings, restore from backup, reset and update from iTunes, and even done a dfu mode reset with no effect at all. Even with no apps at all the crashes continue. My current workaround is to have something playing in the background at zero volume, and it won't crash even when the display is turned off.

Here are some of the relevant logs (they may not be directly related, but they happen about the same time as the crashes).

#### `ResetCounter-2016-11-14-....ips`

```
{"name":"Reset count","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B150)","incident_id":"[omitted]","timestamp":"2016-11-14 07:27:21.66 -0600","bug_type":"115"}
Incident Identifier: [omitted]
CrashReporter Key:   [omitted]
Date: 2016-11-14 07:27:13.61 -0600
Reset count: 0
Boot failure count: 1
Boot faults: 
Boot stage: 80
Boot app: 2681261667
```

#### `log-sessions-2016-11-14-....session`

```
{"os_version":"iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B150)","bug_type":"179"}
{
  "log_timestamp" : "2016-11-14T15:09:44-0600",
  "sessions_data" : [
{
  "app_events" : [
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 184,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T08:15:42-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 2,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T11:16:34-0600"
    }
  ],
  "app_build_version" : "3.3",
  "app_version" : "1.0.1",
  "app_bundleid" : "com.3sprockets.outfolded",
  "app_cohort" : "5|date=1479049200000&sf=143441",
  "app_storefront" : 143441,
  "app_sessionreporter_key" : "56A98EA5-B9FF-4E07-A20F-ED5B8465B7C6",
  "app_adamid" : 1030634472,
  "app_is_beta" : false
},
{
  "app_events" : [
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 723,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T07:47:40-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 209,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T08:04:13-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 288,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T14:57:40-0600"
    }
  ],
  "app_build_version" : "1.8.0",
  "app_version" : "1.8.0",
  "app_bundleid" : "com.rovio.BadPiggies",
  "app_cohort" : "",
  "app_storefront" : 143441,
  "app_sessionreporter_key" : "[omitted]",
  "app_adamid" : 533451786,
  "app_is_beta" : false
},
{
  "app_events" : [
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 11,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T12:49:13-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 178,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T13:23:58-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 2,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T13:28:09-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 358,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T13:48:18-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 12,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T13:54:25-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 12,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T13:54:41-0600"
    }
  ],
  "app_build_version" : "2.2.0",
  "app_version" : "2.2.0",
  "app_bundleid" : "com.yourcompany.Solve",
  "app_cohort" : "",
  "app_storefront" : 143441,
  "app_sessionreporter_key" : "[omitted]",
  "app_adamid" : 351815470,
  "app_is_beta" : false
},
{
  "app_events" : [
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 340,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T07:41:30-0600"
    },
    {
      "type" : "app_session",
      "duration" : 238,
      "state" : "foregroundRunning",
      "date" : "2016-11-14T15:02:29-0600"
    }
  ],
  "app_build_version" : "0",
  "app_version" : "2.02",
  "app_bundleid" : "com.channel4.superarclight",
  "app_cohort" : "5|date=1479049200000&sf=143441",
  "app_storefront" : 143441,
  "app_sessionreporter_key" : "[omitted]",
  "app_adamid" : 1075820557,
  "app_is_beta" : false
}
  ],
  "scheduled" : false,
  "region_format" : "US",
  "os_version" : "iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B150)",
  "log_version" : 2,
  "language" : "en-US",
  "machine_config" : "iPhone5,3"
}
```

#### `awdd-2016-11-14-....consolidated.matriclog.anon`

```
timeestamp: 1479048800691
isAnonymous: true
deviceConfigId: 950
investigationId: 0
model: "iPhone5,3"
softwareBuild: "14B150"
firmwareVersion: "iBoot-3406.20.16"
basebandVersion: "7.01.00"
buildtype: "User"
tz_offset: -21600
metric_file_type: 1
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1478995200000
  triggerId: 2883597
  profileId: 131
  coreRoutineHintSourceUsageSet {
    timestamp: 1478995200000
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
  }
}
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1479081600000
  triggerId: 2883597
  profileId: 131
  coreRoutineHintSourceUsageSet {
    timestamp: 1479081600000
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
  }
}
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1479081600000
  triggerId: 2883597
  profileId: 131
  coreRoutineHintSourceUsageSet {
    timestamp: 1479081600000
    instance {
      hintSource: 2
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
  }
}
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1479081600000
  triggerId: 2883597
  profileId: 131
  coreRoutineHintSourceUsageSet {
    timestamp: 1479081600000
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
  }
}
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1479081600000
  triggerId: 2883598
  profileId: 138
  coreRoutineModelConsistencyReconsolidation {
    timestamp: 1479081600000
    countOfReconsolidatedLOIs: 0
  }
}
metriclogs {
  triggerTime: 1479081600000
  triggerId: 2883597
  profileId: 131
  coreRoutineHintSourceUsageSet {
    timestamp: 1479081600000
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 4
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
    instance {
      hintSource: 3
      isLOI: 1
      isVisit: 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent data - what specific question do you have? Are you looking for a jailbreak mod or other workarounds or ???

Comment: I am hoping for the phone to stop restarting :) I'm open to any solution, and will try just about anything no matter how technical. (I'm a programmer/tech geek)