# iPhone restarting when battery below X%

Tags: iphone, ios, restart

My iPhone restarts "randomly" when the battery is below a certain threshold (which I haven't been able to specifically pinpoint). A couple weeks ago I had the battery replaced with a new one, as battery life wasn't longer than just a couple of hours

The device has iOS 10.2.1, to be upgraded to 10.3 hopefully during the day.

Any ideas of what could be wrong? I've read suggestions about resetting the iPhone, but just sound like a pretty rough/brute solution to implement, although it's an alternative indeed.

Comment: When you say you had the battery replaced - was this at an Apple Store or a 3rd party?

Comment: Unfortunately 3rd Party, as there are no Apple Stores here in Chile, just a few authorized resellers actually

Comment: You likely didn't get a new battery or a good battery. Your best bet is to take it back to the store you bought it from as it sounds like a bad part.

Comment: @jimmy0x52 battery is new, at least Battery Pro app shows that. I've just upgraded to iOS 10.3, and it hasn't restarted (yet), but I guess it still has plenty of charge (62%)

Comment: We're collecting good answers here for a canonical question and answer on phone battery issues: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260946/iphone-5s-suddenly-turns-off-at-30-40-of-battery-life

Answer (score 0):

Certain iPhone 6S models were known to have this problem.  You can check the serial number at this site to see if it's affected (presuming it's a 6s; you didn't specify the model):

https://www.apple.com/support/iphone6s-unexpectedshutdown/

Mine had this problem, and the guys at the Apple Store repaired it (I don't know if it was the battery or a component on the logic board).

For other devices, you may have to try erasing all content and setting it up as a new device and give that a try for a few days to see if that fixes it.  I want to say that my brother had the same symptom and a reset was the solution for him (it's been a while).

I've had an occasional problem with restoring years of accumulated backups and phone migrations that only a fresh install seems to fix.

Comment: OPs tag indicates that the model is a 6, and it appears from the question that the weird shutdowns are in regards to the replacement battery, which certainly wouldn't fall under the recall

Comment: Unfortunately it's a plain "6", not a "6s"

Comment: My brother's was a 6.  It looks like the update however may have quashed the problem.