# How can I prevent jittery video playback on High Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, video

I have a 17-inch MacBook Pro with 2.53 GHz Intel Core i5 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3. I purchased some kids videos from iTunes in 2015/2016 to entertain my kid. Those videos played flawlessly then.

Today, in 2018, I was trying to play exactly the same videos again on the same computer but with latest macOS High Sierra. The videos playback becomes jittery. The sound is still smooth, but the video is like several frames per second, not watchable at all. I've heard Apple deliberately slowed down the iPhones. I'm wondering whether they did the same thing with MacBook Pro.

Update:

I installed El Capitan, and played the same video. It was smooth as it should be. Here are the evidence:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fogEmqSE0ME

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBljv5YnjnY

Comment: I ask whether other people have the same. I think it's clear enough. I asked the question here because of the little line of text under the Ask Different log, which is: Answers for your Apple questions.

Comment: No, they did not do the same thing with your MacBook Pro. Start looking elsewhere for a much more logical explanation. Your MacBook Pro is most likely 8 years old at this point. You could be facing hardware issues (such as worn fans or dirty fans), and you're obviously no longer running the same software as you were 3 years ago...

Comment: I just cleaned my fans actually. Right, what you said is exactly what is happening. The video playback becomes jittery because I'm running a newer version of OS X, they call it macOS now. The OS 3 years ago will play the same video well, but the OS now won't. Is that what you wanted to say?

Comment: That was not what I said. Just install the older version of OS X and try playing your videos.

Comment: It is not the solution. It is a way to gain more information on what is causing the slowness of the video - i.e. a way to gain extra information. You really do not want to be running the old version, unless you happen to be using the laptop only for offline video watching ofcourse.

Comment: I'm installing El Capitan now. I will come back with my result. Of course I don't want to run old version. What I'm after right now is whether Apple deliberately slowed down the video playback on my Mac or not. Give me a couple of hours, I will come back to update.

Comment: The same video played on El Capitan as smooth as it should. Hold on for my videos.

Comment: Now look at the update of my post. Same computer, same video file, different versions of OS, jittery on High Sierra, smooth on El Capitan.

Comment: To complete the test, run `top -o cpu` while running the video, take a screenshot, install High Sierra again and rerun the video. If it still is jittery, take another `top -o cpu` screenshot and add both to the question.

Comment: You seem to hang on to the word “deliberately”, which you cannot prove, and it is counter-productive in order to get your videos playing correctly. Have you tried using VLC to play videos on High Sierra? - i.e. try to establish if this is an issue with the player software, the GPU kernel extension (driver), your configuration, third party software or something else.

Comment: Video bought from Apple store can only played by Apple’s players.

Comment: Yes, but playback similar video (i.e. same resolution, compression, etc).

Comment: Yes, I played other 1080p youtube videos in browser, they are all good.  Only the ones purchased from Apple Store got slowed down.

Comment: @nohillside I got your point. It's a valid point. Now I don't want to invest more time on this any more. What I can tell about the CPU is I'm not doing anything else while playing the videos. I actually have switched to Arch Linux for my daily work since last year. I couldn't be happier. My son wanted to watch some videos so I was trying to play for him on this Mac, but it was disappointing. I used to be a big fan of Apple's products, I mean when Steve Jobs was around. I think this will just signifies the end of my buying Apple things.

Comment: 8 year old machine can no longer keep up. That's the way of the world. The rest is just a rant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is now solved when iTunes is upgrade to 12.8.2 in High Sierra.

Answer (score 6):

**No, Apple did not deliberately slow down your Mac.** (As for deliberately slowing down iPhones see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/310698/168832)).

The reality is I see this sort of thing all the time, on both Macs and PCs, as well as other devices (e.g. smartphones, tablets, etc).

As time goes by the minimum requirements for software and hardware change, and the configuration of a particular system will have a big impact on how long it will continue to keep up with software changes etc.

Without knowing the full specs of your MacBook Pro (e.g. type of storage device, software, etc), it's nevertheless 8 years of age and [obsolete](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201624).

As a result, this model will run Mac OS X El Capitan better than it's going to run macOS High Sierra. And, once you're running a particular version of an operating system, this will have much broader ramifications. It's not just the OS, but bundled software such as browsers that have greater requirements. Additionally, some 3rd party software/hardware will no longer work, or they'll have limitations, hence the need to regularly update/replace them as well.

In general, macOS High Sierra has greater requirements than El Capitan had, and although it still runs on older hardware such as yours, that doesn't mean all features will work on your machine. And while High Sierra can run with 2GB of physical RAM, its requirements are such that it's more RAM hungry than El Capitan was, hence placing a greater burden on your storage device for virtual memory purposes (having a fast SSD is going to handle this better than a traditional hard drive).

In other words, the problem you're experiencing is most likely the result of a scenario something like the following:

1. macOS High Sierra needs more memory to run (both in terms of RAM and graphics)
2. It therefore uses more of your physical 8GB RAM, thereby leaving less RAM available for other software etc
3. In response, macOS High Sierra makes more use of virtual memory to help manage the limited memory resources
4. This places a much greater burden on your storage drive which is having to deal with a lot more read/write operations
5. Your video playing software is potentially having to make more use of virtual memory and your storage drive is having to perform even more read/write operations as it has to deliver the video as well as everything else it's doing
6. End result: A stuttered playback experience.

**Summary**

The **overall** burden on your system from having High Sierra installed (along with all of its associated software etc) is much greater than having El Capitan installed. And, this overall burden will be more obvious with some functions than it will be with others. Unfortunately, playing video files is one such candidate for this.

If you had a 2011 MBP you might have been able to address this by increasing your RAM to 16GB, but that's not an option here. If you don't have an SSD already, then installing one will definitely help. If playing videos is the main purpose of this machine, then leaving it with El Capitan installed may be an option for you. Otherwise it's time to reconsider your setup as your MBP is no longer able to meet all of your needs.

Comment: No, I am most certainly **not** paid by Apple to write long answers here or anywhere else for that matter. LOL My answer, however, is one explanation for what you're experiencing - but of course that was based on the info originally included in your question, so its application in your case is somewhat diminished now. In hindsight, I should have asked you for more details before drafting my answer.

Comment: That said, I'm a little confused by your statement above that you have no choice to play these videos in iTunes or Real Time Player and that Apple doesn't allow you to play these videos elsewhere? What software are you playing them on? Maybe we can still get to the bottom of this?

Comment: For the videos, music bought from the Apple Store, you can play them only in Apple's players. They even ask you to login your Apple ID before you can play those paid audios/videos.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Apologies, I mistook your earlier comment to mean you couldn't play them in iTunes, but I see now that's not what you were saying. I'd be interested to see what would happen if you actually logged in via iTunes in macOS High Sierra and re-downloaded one of the movies you've previously purchased to see how well it plays? That may help diagnose the issue.

Comment: The story started from what you said. I downloaded the videos in latest OS, latest iTunes, and it sucked. That made me trace back to the old version of OS, videos from USB, and etc.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer.  It also underscores my frustration with Apple's decision to make it impossible for users to upgrade their RAM...

Comment: OMG, what is the incentive for you to write such a long article without any proof of anything. I have purchased the same video from Youtube again and they play flawlessly on the same Mac. Now I have moved everything to Arch Linux, and I won't spend a penny on Apple. I looked at your other activities in this site, and I probably know this might be your job.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Nope, not my job (but I wish it was - then I'd be getting paid for all the time I spend here). Anyway, I stand by my answer - it's unclear to me on what basis you've decided I am wrong? If I recall correctly, you ended up reinstalling an older version of macOS and the videos worked fine again - so that goes some way to backing up my answer - namely that as time goes by the demands an operating system places on hardware increases and it's for that reason that hardware can struggle.

Comment: This is just the way things go over time. It's the same for PCs as well. I have two PCs that can't run Windows 10 at all. That's just life. Your Mac can't run macOS Mojave, but *can* run macOS High Sierra - but that doesn't mean it'll perform well on High Sierra. Simple solution - install an older version of macOS or another OS that's not as demanding. But as for Apple ***deliberately*** slowing down *your* specific model of Mac, that's just ridiculous and there's no evidence whatsoever for that.

Comment: I think the evidence is clear enough, the two youtube video links and I can play all other videos smoothly with the same Mac on High Sierra. I don't understand what incentive you have to defend Apple without any evidence at all.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't your *evidence* show that the videos play fine in El Capitan and not High Sierra? Or do the videos show something else?