# iPhone 5 shuts down at 25% on iOS 7.0.4

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, restore, bug

My iPhone 5 has been shutting down earlier than normal at lower battery levels.

First, it started to shut down around 10%, then it increased to 15%, 20%, and finally 25%. I used to be able to run it down to 1%.

The battery indicator also jumps down sometimes by around 10-15%.

I have only had this problem ever since updating to iOS 7.0.4 (from 7.0.3). I have done multiple iTunes restores since I updated, but the problem still has not been fixed.

Is there a fix for it?

Comment: Mine started shutting down at 3% and now it shuts down around 11-12%. Slowly creeping up...

Comment: It shut down at 50% today

Comment: See this question about a similar situation: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113508/regular-crashes-on-iphone-4s-ios-6-1-1-due-to-old-battery-or-because-of-update

Comment: Here's some information extracted from the battery:
 
 CycleCount: 370
 DesignCapacity: 1430
 FullChargeCapacity: 953

Answer (score 3):

I called Apple about this and they said 2 things:

1. the numbers provided are approximate
2. certain apps in background can be battery hogs. She specifically said that the camera app native to iOS7 continues full battery use in background and they were aware of this. She suggested being careful NOT to keep camera in background (i.e. double tap iOS button and slide camera up to remove from background active list)

This must have been the problem for me because battery life immediately improved. It still shuts down soon after going below 20% but it had been at 25% when I called.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just about time to replace the battery

Comment: Hi welcome to AskDifferent, I find if a question is worth answering it is worth upvoting.  Also some reasoning and a link may get you more upvotes. Please take the time to read the Answer and Question section of the [help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) page.